# Thin client message "not enough space" when unpacking the cab

Tags: windows-ce, cab

I am installing a .net (CF) app using a cab, on a thin client running WinCE 6.0. When I first install it, everything is fine, and the app gets installed in the specified location.

Just out of curiosity, I clicked on the same CAB again and was greeted with "Not enough space" message. None of the files were modified...so it doesn't make any sense at all....

Are there any settings in the CAB I should be using to avoid this?

I have been using CAB for 3 years now and haven't seen this type of a message yet. The message would make sense if files were changed and got bigger. But if no change happened, something is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the hard drive on the think client almost completely full? It sounds to me like it has just enough space to install it and then when you try to execute it again, it can't find enough free space on the hard drive.

Comment: But it doesn't make any sense...it's the same cab, containing the same files. From what I understand, it just overwrites the existing files...why would it have enough space the first time and not enough the second time.....

Comment: Ah...I thought it said "Not enough space" before you tried installing, as in it check the hard drive space and didn't find enough free space. At what part in the process of installing the cab does it say 'not enough space'?

Comment: before installing. But what I don't understand is - isn't installation just supposed to over-write the files? and if it's exact same CAB as before, this issue shouldn't come up....

Comment: Technically, it should, but it may be detecting files already exist and trying to write to a different directory so as to not overwrite the previous files. It's difficult to speculate when we don't know the exact settings applied to the CAB.

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere4/r41/vsp_41_vm_admin_guide.pdf

(Ctrl-F type in "full" or Disk)

Comment: Including an external reference to a well documented source is appreciated here on Stack Overflow but it is important to include in your answer the most important/relevant snippets from the external source and give context as to how to answer the question because if that link goes dead (server goes down, etc), then your answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 1):

I think the installer only checks the registry to detect a previous installation of the same program and it does not check if the files from the previous installation are still present or not. If they were deleted, or the file system is not persistent, then the new installation process does not have anything to overwrite.
On top of that, even if the files are present, the installation will also has to make sure that the file sizes are the same (they could be zero due to some file system corruption for example). Still I might be forgetting some other edge situations.
I suppose for performance and consistency reasons it is easier just to ask for more free space.